# Can closing port 80 lead to more security?

Tags: tls, webserver, http, ports

If a website is running on HTTPS only, is it reasonable to close port 80 of the web server and only leave port 443 open? Does this action provide more security for the website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all sites leave port 80 open and have it issue a redirect to https://...

The reason for this is that is your site is `https://mysite.com/` then most users will access the site by typing `mysite.com` and their browser will initially try `http://mysite.com/` If you've closed port 80 then their request will fail.

The security merits of this have been discussed in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44843/how-secure-is-redirecting-user-from-http-normal-bank-com-to-https-secure-ban). It is more secure to disable HTTP, but for most sites the reduction is usability is not worth it. [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is an option to consider.

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't it make sense if browsers were redesigned to try `https` if `http` fails?

Comment: @Cruncher in that case it would, following the general principle of "turn off everything you don't need". But I can't see browsers making that change any time soon.

Comment: Update, nearly 5 years on... I can now see browsers doing this some time soon.